# Solving LPP in r

Tags: r, linear-programming

Weight of per unit product:

• Juice 600g

• Cheese 150g

• Bread 200g

• You have to carry 15kg of food

• Assuming you know that the store where you buy sausages will have a maximum of 30 Bread in stock.

```
obj.in  <- c(.6,  .15, .2)

const.mat <- matrix(c(.6,  .15,  .2,
                      0, 0, 1,
                      nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))


weight_constraint <- 15
p3_constraint <- 6

const.rhs <- c(price_constraint, p3_constraint)

const.dir  <- c("=", "<=")

optimum <-  lp(direction="max",  obj.in, const.mat, const.dir,  const.rhs)
optimum
```

Result

```
Error: status 3
```

Can anyone help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `const.mat` closing `)` is misplaced.  Running the OP's code results in a single column `matrix` instead of the `nrow = 2` mentioned

```
const.mat <- matrix(c(.6,  .15,  .2,
                  0, 0, 1),
                  nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Also, assuming that as `price_constraint` was not defined

```
const.rhs <- c(weight_constraint, p3_constraint)
```

If we use the changed data

```
library(lpSolve)
lp(direction="max",  obj.in, const.mat, const.dir,  const.rhs)
#Success: the objective function is 15
```

Comment: Thanks for marking my mistakes. But I solved it by hand and results in 23,0,6.
But This is giving me 25, 0,0.